# React.js input performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to set up some inputs on page with EN value (left column inputs) and RU value (right column inputs). Input with EN value is read-only. Input with RU value can be changed.

After change I can POST my new value to server.

What I don't understand:
in file scripts/react/components/InputsRow.js:61 I have a DIV element, and all OK.
[Github link](https://github.com/maxfarseer/react-inputs/blob/master/scripts/react/components/InputsRow.js#L61)

```
render: function() {
var result = this.state.data,
    keys = result.keys,
    values = result.values,
    locale_id = result.locale_id,
    project_id = result.project_id,
    version_id = result.version_id,
    self = this;

console.log('<InputsRow /> render');

var inputNodes = keys.map && keys.map(function(item, keyIndex) {
  var keyId = item.id;
  return (
    <div className="row" key={keyIndex} className={'inputs-row ' + (item.disabled ? 'inputs-row_disabled':'')}>
      <div className="col-md-12">
        <div className="col-md-6 form-group">
          <div className="input-group">
            <div className="input-group-addon">
              <i className="fa fa-info fa-fw"></i>
            </div>
            {/*<input className="key-input form-control" value={item.name} onClick={self.onInputKeyClick.bind(self,item)} readOnly />*/}
            <div className="key-input form-control">{item.name}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <LocalValues localObj={values[keyId]} locale_id={locale_id} project_id={project_id} sendItem={self.sendItem} key_id= {keyId}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
return (
  <div>
    <div>{inputNodes}</div>
  </div>
)
```

},

If you try to uncomment line 60 and comment line 61 - you get a problem with 'RU inputs'. When you typed any symbols - it's will work so slowly...

I have a git repo for best declaration this problem:

https://github.com/maxfarseer/react-inputs

P.S. 'RU inputs' = right column.

Comment: What do you mean by EN value and RU value?

Comment: English and Russian ??? - but that's just a guess

Comment: Sry, all. Left Inputs - EN, Right inputs - RU

Comment: @Crob - En value = left column (inputs with english value), Ru value = right column (inputs with russian value)

Comment: I'm not saying that this is the core problem, but I can see on Github that you are emitting a change in your data-store (`InputsRowStore.js`) every time an action is dispatched. You should emit a change in each of the action call-backs (your switch-case).
Also the `sendItem={self.sendItem}` in line 61 seems a bit off...

Comment: Why are you binding click that way in the input? Have you tried using `onChange` or `onKeyUp` instead?

Comment: @DanaWoodman yeap, I tried.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was chrome bug (?).
I download chrome nightly and haven't problems with perfomance. Try to do same in last Safari - no problems again.
I try to disable all extensions and try to disable all bootstrap styles on this input - nothings happen.

(stable) Chrome 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit) has perfomance problem

(nightly) Chrome 45.0.2452.0 canary (64-bit) - no problems

(stable) Safari 8.0.7 (10600.7.12) - no problems

Comment: I highly doubt this is a Chrome bug... Most likely it is an issue with your dispatching/subscribing to events or with how you're using binding. If you haven't yet, please read up on controlled inputs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: @DanaWoodman, ok if it's not chrome bug, why canary chrome and safari - work great ? I try to find solution more time and read all about controlled and uncontrolled inputs. I can do mistake, ofcourse, but nice work in other browsers (or browser version)...

Comment: Generally it's best to assume that your code is at fault before pointing to such a well supported codebase like Chrome. What I would try is to remove absolutely everything you can in your example code up until the point where the failure still occurs. If you repost the bare minimum test case we can be more helpful troubleshooting.

Comment: Unrelated, you don't need to wrap your `React.render` call in jQuery.

Comment: @DanaWoodman, it is bare minimum test ;) It's my first question with full example - github repo ;) ok, this code may be not the best, but problem from this example occurs only in current chrome.